# python - getting integer object is not iterable in below code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi when I am running below code in python I am getting an exception int object is not iterable. Can you please let me know what I am missing here.

```py
def myfunc(string):
    temp = ''
    for i,l in range(0,len(string)):
        if(i%2==0):
            temp +=l.upper()
        else:
            temp +=l.lower()
    return temp
```

Comment: To get better answers in the future, you might have added an example call to your function. String can be anything

Comment: sure Ohir, I will

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the result of `list(range(0,len(string)))`:

```
>>> string = "Hello"
>>> list(range(0,len(string)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It's a list of *integers*. `for i, l in ...` attempts to unpack an element of this utterable into two variables, `i` and `l`. It's impossible to do this for an integer, obviously. Continuing from the previous example:

```
>>> i, l = _[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Here's what you may be looking for:

```
for i, l in enumerate(string):
    ...
```

`enumerate` yields `(index, value)` pairs:

```
>>> list(enumerate(string))
[(0, 'H'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'l'), (3, 'l'), (4, 'o')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,l in range(0,len(string)):
```

`range` returns a iterable of integers in a interval

So it should be:

```
for i in range(0,len(string)):
```

Comment: Actually it should be `for i, l in enumerate(string)`

Comment: *Range returns a iterable of ints. Just a nitpick.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want all the characters at even positions to be in uppercase and characters at odd positions to be in lower case
So I believe this will work.
Happy Coding..

```
def myfunc(string):
temp = ''
for i in range(0,len(string)):
    if(i%2==0):
        temp +=string[i].upper()
    else:
        temp +=string[i].lower()
return(temp)
```